# Mysqli recibe un valor diferente al enviado

Tags: php, mysqli

Realizo una consulta insert en la cual genera un codigo aleatoreo y lo inserta junto a dos datos mas, pero el dato aleatoreo no se envia y en su lugar aparece un mismo numero repetido(en mysqli)
El Campo codigo_galeria es int 20 not null, creado desde myAdmin. nada del otro mundo

```
$titulo_album = $_POST["titulo"];
  $intro_album = $_POST["intro"];

  //codigo unico para identificar la galeria
  $codigo_fecha = date("YmdHis");
  $no_aleatorio = rand(100,999);
  $codigojunto = $codigo_fecha.$no_aleatorio; //17 digitos aleatoreos

  require('dbcall.php');
  if (!$cnn) {
    die("Conexion fallida :" . mysqli_connect_error());
  }else {
    $sql = mysqli_prepare($cnn, "INSERT INTO datos_galerias (id_galeria,codigo_galeria,titulo_galeria,intro_galeria) VALUES (NULL,?,?,?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql,"iss",$codigojunto,utf8_decode($titulo_album),utf8_decode($intro_album));

    if (mysqli_stmt_execute($sql) == TRUE) {
        echo "<script> console.log('$codigojunto');</script>";
        //Me arroja caracteres diferentes como deberia ser, ejem: 20190620161458354

    }else {
      echo "<script> console.log('Ocurrio un error al crear la galeria');</script>";
    }
```

Pero como mencione no funciona, esto es lo que guarda siempre codigo_galeria columna 2: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No encuentro el error, que podria ser?

Comment: ¿Que tipo de campo es? ¿Como has creado la tabla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

17 dígitos son demasiados para una columna `integer`.

Los campos `integer` no se comportan como los campos de texto, donde el número indica la longitud máxima de la cadena. Por ejemplo, `varchar(20)` puede contener una cadena de texto de hasta 20 caracteres. Sin embargo, `integer(20)` no deja de ser un entero de 32 bits, que puede contener un número entre -2147483648 y 2147483647. El 20 se tiene en cuenta solo a la hora de mostrar el número, no al almacenarlo.

Yo utilizaría un `unsigned bigint`, que pueden almacenar números entre 0 y 18446744073709551615, o un `char(20)`:

`ALTER TABLE datos_galerias MODIFY codigo_galeria UNSIGNED BIGINT;`

Explicación en inglés: https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/mysql-int11-what-does-it-means/

Comment: efectivamente, gracias por la aclaración